# How can I control pressing key speed programatically?(Python)

Tags: python, keyboard

I've found this "SendKeys" Python Module.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SendKeys/0.3

This module helps me to press keyboard keys programatically.
But it's pressing speed is too fast for what I am intended to do.
Is there a solution to control this speed?

Comment: Have you tried sleep()?

Comment: Oh I didn't mentioned, sleep() function makes a term between each keys.
But I want to make it actual pressing speed slower.

Comment: In C# I found there is key press delay
http://www.ranorex.com/Documentation/Net/html/M_Ranorex_Control_SendKeys_2.htm
How can I implement it with python?